# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string SQL Server 2016

Tags: java, sql-server, date, jdbc, type-conversion

Hello so i have a these code that have you enter a year, a month, a day all string into a text field and then it will combine them to make one string and used a statement to make query convert this to date and inserting it and some other data into a database here is the code.

```
    int CustomerID = Integer.parseInt(txtCustomerID.getText());
    int CarID = Integer.parseInt(txtCarID.getText());
    String startdateyear = txtStartDateYear.getText();
    String startdatemonth = txtStartDateMonth.getText();
    String startdateday = txtStartDateDay.getText();
    String enddateyear = txtEndDateYear.getText();
    String enddatemonth = txtEndDateMonth.getText();
    String enddateday = txtEndDateDay.getText();
    String StartDate = startdateyear + startdatemonth + startdateday;
    String EndDate = enddateyear + enddatemonth + enddateday;
    int HiringPrice = Integer.parseInt(txtHiringPrice.getText());
    String Pay = txtPay.getText();
    carDA.insert(CustomerID, CarID, StartDate, EndDate, HiringPrice, Pay);/
```

This is the Insert Query:

```
stm.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO CarOrder VALUES (" + CarID +"," + CustomerID +",CONVERT(DATE," + "'" +StartDate+ "', 111), CONVERT(DATE," + "'" +EndDate+"', 111)," +HiringPrice+ "," +"'"+Pay+ "')");
```

When i run the program it throws this message:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I cant seem to find out why it is doing this, if any one can help me i will be thankful.

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent SQL injection. It will also solve your converter problem

Comment: @Jens i don't get you when you said `It will also solve your converter problem` can you please check my answer above is that the correct way you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the **date format** you enter is not correct is should look like :

```
convert(datetime, '2017/06/24', 111) -- yyyy/mm/dd
```

because you are using the `111` so your input should look like `yyyy/mm/dd`, read more about this [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

---

To avoid syntax error or SQL Inject i suggect to use PreparedStatement instead, it is more helpful and more secure.

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");

String query = "INSERT INTO CarOrder VALUES (?, ?, CONVERT(DATE, ?, 111), CONVERT(DATE, ?, 111), ?, ?)";
try (PreparedStatement insert = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
    insert.setInt(1, CustomerID);
    insert.setDate(2, new Date);
    insert.setDate(3, format.parse(StartDate));
    insert.setDate(4, format.parse(EndDate));
    insert.setDouble(5, HiringPrice);//i think the price is a double maybe you make it int or float so you have to use the right type
    insert.setString(6, Pay);

    insert.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: I am ot sute if you need the convert statement, But yes that is what i mean

Comment: **why this down-vote?** the op said it work so why this down-vote

Answer (score 1):

You are getting invalid string here:

```
String StartDate = startdateyear + startdatemonth + startdateday;
```

For example, startdateyear = '2016', startdatemonth = '4', startdateday = '1' --> StartDate = '201641' --> `select CONVERT(DATE,'201641', 111)` -->

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

Why on the earth do you use 111 format that is `yy/mm/dd` while your string does not contain `/` at all? That '201641' is interpreted like year=2020, month=16, day=41